# Newbie learning PostgreSQL help adding update to a query statement

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I a leaning PostgreSQL and need help with an update query. first and foremost what to thank everybody in the forum for helping me.

I have a temp table that was made with data imported from a spreadsheet. I need to update another table with the value of "f" (for false) base on the temp table. I had to inner join another table to get the linking key for all tables. I am stuck on how to update one of the inner join tables with the value of "f". here is what I have so far. Any help would be appreciated

I hope I am explaining this correctly?

```
SELECT
 DISTINCT ON
  (fttemp.fttemp_venditem_numb) fttemp.fttemp_venditem_numb,
  item.item_number,
  item.item_id,
  item.item_descrip1,
  itemsite.itemsite_id,
  itemsite.itemsite_sold,
  itemsite.itemsite_posupply
FROM
 fttemp
 INNER JOIN item ON fttemp.fttemp_venditem_numb = item.item_number
 INNER JOIN itemsite ON item.item_id = itemsite_item_id

ORDER BY
 fttemp.fttemp_venditem_numb
```

---

I only want to update itemsite.itemsite_sold and itemsite.itemsite_posupply with the value of "f" from the itemsite table only base on the fttemp table.

Comment: You want to update *all* rows from `itemside` that are matched by the join? Why the `DISTINCT ON`?

Comment: I want to update only two rows (itemsite_sold and itemsite_posupply).

Comment: The DISTINCT ON because the fttemp table has only two rows, fttemp_venditem_numb and fttemp_item_descrip1. I was getting the wrong record count without it

Comment: You are mixing up columns and rows. My question was not if you want to update all *columns*.